# Error when source (sourceCpp()) a file using RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I encountered an error when trying to source a .cpp file that used RcppArmadillo. My code is simple:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double basic(double x){
  return x*2.0;
}
```

The error is below:

```
> sourceCpp("learn2.cpp")
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lquadmath
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sourceCpp_5.so] Error 1
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include   -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Users/Chen/Library/R/3.6/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"/Users/Chen" -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c learn2.cpp -o learn2.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o sourceCpp_5.so learn2.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
Error in sourceCpp("learn2.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

There is a resolved [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758987/error-in-r-with-rcpp-and-rcpparmadillo-using-sourcecpp), but doesn't seem to help for my case. I tried the method by Crystal on 02/14/15 (installing gfortran-4.2.3.pkg), but that did not solve the problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you installed the proper Xcode and CLT for your unstated version of OSX? And the current page for development tolls for OSX gives this as the gfortran distribution: https://mac.r-project.org/tools/gfortran-8.2-Mojave.dmg

Comment: I did update the link in Dirk's answer. Ir's been changed recently

Comment: I generally cannot keep track of things on macOS as I don't use it -- but we _do_ point to this resource by @coatless right from our GitHub repo and its issue tickets:  https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/

Comment: And as this really is duplicate and a FAQ, I closed it.  In short, _not_ an RcppArmadillo but simply a mean-spirited conspiracy between Apple Inc. and R to make your life harder than it would be a on a Linux box.  Such is life.  Kidding aside, _R on macOS_ needs special care.  And that is not an Rcpp or RcppArmadillo issue.

Comment: Hehhehe : I certainly didn't mean to imply that you needed to keep track of any of the OSX details. I was merely trying to give JChen current information about to find stuff for his machine.

Comment: Thank you both for the kind responses. Problem solved.